# Tikz - loglog Scale with strange powers of 10

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis, decimal-number

I am trying to plot some data from numerical simulations and I want to display the data (see code below). But the powers of 10 do have strange additional decimal places (see picture). Is there a way to get rid of these strange decimal places?

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        height = 10cm, % standard 10cm
        width = 15cm,  % standard 10cm
        xlabel = {$N$},
        ylabel = {$e_h$},
        grid=both,
        major grid style={black!50},
        xmode=log, ymode=log,
        xmin=1e0, xmax=1e4,
        ymin=1e-3, ymax=1e1,
        yticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/precision=0,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill
        },
        scaled y ticks=false,
        xticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/precision=0,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill
        },
        scaled y ticks=false,   
        cycle list name=my black white
        ]
        \addplot table [x=N, y = eh, col sep=comma] {Plots/results2.txt};
        \legend{$e_h$}
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

EDIT: General pdfkeys settings:

```
%=========== Gloabal Tikz settings
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\pgfplotsset{
    height = 10cm,
    width = 10cm,
    tick pos = left,
    legend style={at={(0.98,0.66)}, anchor=east},
    legend cell align=left,     
    }
 \pgfkeys{
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    fixed,
    %fixed zerofill,
    precision = 1,
    set thousands separator = {}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I removed `/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill`

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        height = 10cm, % standard 10cm
        width = 15cm,  % standard 10cm
        xlabel = {$N$},
        ylabel = {$e_h$},
        grid=both,
        major grid style={black!50},
        xmode=log, ymode=log,
        xmin=1e0, xmax=1e4,
        ymin=1e-3, ymax=1e1,
        yticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/precision=0
        },
        scaled y ticks=false,
        xticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/precision=0
        },
        scaled y ticks=false,  
        %cycle list name=my black white
        ]
       % \addplot table [x=N, y = eh, col sep=comma] {Plots/results2.txt};
      %  \legend{$e_h$}
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for your answer. But is still get these nasty decimals. I added my general settings.

Comment: You haven't posted a compilable MWE so its difficult to fully diagnose your problem. But I just tried it with those settings and it works fine for me. No decimals .

Comment: Thank you a lot! I found the problem I had a separate piece in which I defined additional pgfkeys! The problem ist solved.